# Customize JAXB binding

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I am new to JAXB world and facing an issue. First of all I don't even know if it is possible or not, and if it is possible then how to do it.

I have this XSD file (trimmed down version)

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:complexType name="nillableString">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="nil" type="xsd:boolean"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="NillableIntegerType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
      <!-- not the right pattern, but the right pattern isn't working ("[-+]?\d*") -->
      <xsd:pattern value="[\-+0-9]*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="nillableInteger">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="NillableIntegerType">
        <xsd:attribute name="nil" type="xsd:boolean"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="mainclass">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="prop1" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="prop2" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:choice>
      <xsd:attribute name="product" use="optional" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="prop1">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="name" type="nillableString" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="prop2">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="priority" type="nillableInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="backup_rule" type="nillableString" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:choice>
      <!-- no attributes -->
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I then used xjc tool to generate Java Beans from this XSD file. However, my Java bean property looks like this

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "prop1", type = Prop1.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "prop2", type = Prop2.class)
})
protected List<Object> prop1OrProp2;
```

However, I would like my bean to appear as

```
@XmlElement(name = "prop1", type = Prop1.class)
protected Prop1 prop1;

@XmlElement(name = "prop2", type = Prop2.class)
protected Prop2 prop2;
```

Is this even possible? If yes, please point me on how can I do it? (I tried following http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148366 but I got completely lost)

In this way I would be able to set each property explicitly. This is just a simple example, but in actual XSD I have about 30 properties.

Comment: The problem here is that you put the properties into a `<choice>` tag. If you have multiple of this constructs in your XSD I'd say that the design of your XSD is wrong. It looks like you have multiple "types" of documents but instead of distinguishing those at the top most level you "tweak" the detail entries.

Comment: Thanks mate. I removed the maxOccurs="unbounded" from the xsd:choice and added attribute maxOccurs="1" to xsd:element. This gives me what I wanted. Unfortunately, I can't edit the xsd but your explanation made sense as why it was a collection as opposed to individual element